# Sql query to find the dates between two

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

I have a problem that I would like to get the dates which are logged between two dates (i.e start& end dates).

I have a table with the following records in it:

Create table t ( a int, b date, c date );

```
insert into t values(1, to_date( '01-jan-2015'), to_date( '15-jan-2015'));
insert into t values(2, to_date( '03-jan-2015'), to_date( '10-jan-2015'));
insert into t values(3, to_date( '12-jan-2015'), to_date( '25-jan-2015'));
insert into t values(4, to_date( '20-jan-2015'), to_date( '01-feb-2015'));
insert into t values(5, to_date( '05-feb-2015'), to_date( '10-feb-2015'));
```

Is there any way using a SELECT statement to determine the dates that exist within the date range given in this table?

EX: the value between '01-jan-2015' to_date  '15-jan-2015' is already there. 
Anyways there is again two values logged on '03-jan-2015' and '12-jan-2015'. (whereas those were alreday defined between('01-jan-2015' to_date  '15-jan-2015'))
So, I need to get the output as `"values for start_date "'03-jan-2015' is already logged"` without giving the date range in the query. that is, it should automatically pull the record for given value.

**This assumes that when date ranges overlap, it will eliminate a overload of values between the date range**

Hope this makes sense.Kindly help me on to solve this.

Thanks, 
Shruthi

Comment: This is almost the same scenario that you can adjust a little to apply to your problem ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755634/select-between-two-date/48756731#48756731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query, that will list out all the overlapping entries.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t as t1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    t as t2
        WHERE   t1.a != t2.a
            AND t1.b <= t2.c AND t1.c >= t2.b
    )
```

Or try this with a left join

```
SELECT  t1.*,t2.a as overlap_id
FROM    t as t1
LEFT JOIN t as t2   ON t1.a > t2.a
            AND t1.b <= t2.c AND t1.c >= t2.b
WHERE   t2.a IS NOT NULL

a   b           c           overlap_id
--------------------------------------
2   2015-01-03  2015-01-10  1         --2 overlapped with 1
3   2015-01-12  2015-01-25  1         --3 overlapped with 1
4   2015-01-20  2015-02-01  3         --4 overlapped with 3
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul.
But ,How do i get the records that are made in between (If logged) the overlapping entries. i.e
I need to derive only the entries for "'03-jan-2015'" (from above data given) without giving the date range

Comment: in the data u give, record 1 is overlapped with record 2 and vice versa, also the record 3 is overlapped with 4  and vice versa.

Comment: Also the record 3 is overlapped with both 1 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select * FROM AnyTable WHERE 
              start_date  <= '03-jan-2015' and end_date  >= '03-jan-2015'
```